# TypeError: Network request failed in react-native

Tags: react-native, .net-core

When I use Postman, I can successfully send a request to this address: `https://localhost:9001/api/Account/authenticate`.

However, my react-native app throws an error for the same request:

> TypeError: Network request failed

Here's my request code:

```js
_login() {
    var api = API.concat("api/Account/authenticate");
    api = 'https://localhost:9001/api/Account/authenticate';
    fetch(api, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'email': 'superadmin@gmail.com',
            'password': '123Pa$$word!',
        }),

    })
        // .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("res.status", res.status);
            console.log('data: ', res.data);
            //  console.log('jwToken: ', res.data.jwToken);
            console.log('message: ', res.message);
            console.log('api:', api);                  
        });
}
```

Comment: I corrected a syntax error that looked like a typo in your code (nothing to do with your Network error). However, you should make sure that this edit was accurate.

Comment: I also recommend including the request details from Postman. I see that you have found an answer, but this is beneficial to other users down the road; we'd just be guessing at your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml** on your **adroid/app/src/main** directory

And android emulator or device is have their own OS so you can't access it by `localhost`.

Try change

`https://localhost:9001/api/Account/authenticate`

To

`https://10.0.2.2:9001/api/Account/authenticate`

Comment: Yes, it have in file  AndroidManifest.xml. I use: adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:56789 tcp:56789 it work. But not show JWT json data like Postman.

Comment: please read my updated answer, hopefully it work

Answer (score 0):

**Have a try with the below modifications :**

```
login = () => {
    var api = API.concat("api/Account/authenticate");
    api='https://localhost:9001/api/Account/authenticate';
    fetch({
        url: api,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: 'superadmin@gmail.com',
            password: '123Pa$$word!',
        }),
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("res.status", res.status);
        console.log('data: ', res.data);
        //  console.log('jwToken: ', res.data.jwToken);
        console.log('message: ', res.message);
        console.log('api:', api);                  
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error : ', err.message)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It work

```
_login() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "email": "superadmin@gmail.com",
        "password": "123Pa$$word!"
    });

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    var api = API.concat("api/Account/authenticate"); 
         
    fetch(api, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {  
            console.log('succeeded: ', result.succeeded);  
            console.log('message: ', result.message);  
            console.log('errors : ', result.errors);           
            console.log("res", result);
            console.log('data: ', result.data);       
            console.log("res.data.jwtoken: ", result.data.jwToken);             
            console.log('api:', api);     
        })           
  
}
```